# will there be any change if numeric:true is set in localeCompare function

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have table values with numeric and string types and want to know that setting numeric true will bring any changes for sorting string values in the column

Comment: Depends on the data. Did you [read the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, treating data as numeric can indeed change the order. Consider this:

```js
const column = [ "1", "3", "10", "24", "212" ];

column.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b));
console.log("lexicographical sort:", column);

column.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, undefined, { numeric: true }));
console.log("sort with numeric collation:", column);
```

Lexicographical sorting places `"10"` before `"2"` because `"1" < "2"` as opposed to checking the entire numbers. This can work if you have the same names, too:

```js
const column = [ "file_1", "file_3", "file_10", "file_24", "file_212" ];

column.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b));
console.log("lexicographical sort:", column);

column.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, undefined, { numeric: true }));
console.log("sort with numeric collation:", column);
```

But might be undesirable in some situations, if you *don't* want to treat numbers as a whole unit:

```js
const column = [ "1 Somewhere Street", "3 Some Avenue", "10 Some Avenue", "24 Parking", "212 Whatever Road" ];

column.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b));
console.log("lexicographical sort:", column);

column.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, undefined, { numeric: true }));
console.log("sort with numeric collation:", column);

column.sort((a, b) => {
  const regex = /^(\d+)\s+(.*)/;
  const [, numericA, stringA] = a.match(regex);
  const [, numericB, stringB] = b.match(regex);
  
  return stringA.localeCompare(stringB) 
    || numericA.localeCompare(numericB, undefined, { numeric: true })
});
console.log("sort with starting numerics treated last:", column);
```

So, it depends on what your data looks like and how you want it presented.